# Cannot get any values from LWC @wire

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Sorry, hoping I'm just doing something dumb here, but I'm really struggling with my first attempt at a lightning web component and was wondering if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong.

So my objective here is to simply get the Status of an Order using `@wire` `getRecord`.  This is to run in a lightning partner community, but it seems to be showing the same outcomes in standard lighting.

Here is some stripped back code.

**Wrapper Aura (as it will be a quick action):**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

    THIS IS A TEST

    <c:orderActivate orderId="8010k000000XgoDAAS"/>

</aura:component>
```

**LWC HTML**

```
<!-- Order Activate -->
<template>

    <lightning-combobox
            label="How will the order be paid?"
            options={paymentOptions}
            value={paymentOption}
            onchange={handlePaymentOptionChange}
            required
    ></lightning-combobox>

    orderStatus:  {orderStatus}

    isLoading: {isLoading}

        <div if:true={isOption2}>
            <div if:true={wiredOrder.data}>

            <label class="slds-text-heading_medium">
                Please confirm your vendor's details:
            </label>

            <div class="slds-form">
                <div class="slds-text-heading_small">
                    Vendor Details
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**LWC Controller**

```
import {LightningElement, api, track, wire} from 'lwc';
import {getRecord, getFieldValue} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const OPTION_1 = 'OPT 1',
    OPTION_2 = 'OPT 2';

const PAYMENT_OPTIONS = [
    {
        value: OPTION_1,
        label: "Option 1"
    },
    {
        value: OPTION_2,
        label: "Option 2"
    }
];

//Fields
import FIELD_ORDER_STATUS from "@salesforce/schema/Order.Status";

const ORDER_FIELDS = [
    FIELD_ORDER_STATUS
];

export default class OrderActivate extends LightningElement {

    @track
    paymentOptions = PAYMENT_OPTIONS;

    @track isOption2;

    @api orderId;

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$orderId', ORDER_FIELDS})
    wiredOrder;

    get isLoading() {
        console.log("isLoading", this.wiredOrder.data);
        console.log("isLoading", this.wiredOrder.error);
        return !this.wiredOrder || (!this.wiredOrder.data && !this.wiredOrder.error);
    }

    __paymentOption;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(ORDER_FIELDS);
        console.log(this.orderId);
    }

    get orderStatus() {
        console.log(getFieldValue(this.wiredOrder, FIELD_ORDER_STATUS));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(getFieldValue(this.wiredOrder, FIELD_ORDER_STATUS)));
        return getFieldValue(this.wiredOrder, FIELD_ORDER_STATUS);
    }

    handlePaymentOptionChange(event) {
        this.__paymentOption = event.detail.value;
        if(!this.__paymentOption) {
            this.option2 = false;
            return;
        }
        if(this.__paymentOption === OPTION_2) {
            this.option2 = true;
            return;
        }
        this.option2 = false;
    }

    errorCallback(error, stack) {
        console.error(error, stack);
    }

}
```

So what happens is the console prints this on `connectedCallback()`:

```
Array [ "Order.Status" ]
orderActivate.js:4:1801
8010k000000XgoDAAS orderActivate.js:4:1816
Proxy { <target>: {}, <handler>: {…} }
orderActivate.js:4:1873
{} orderActivate.js:4:1921
isLoading undefined orderActivate.js:4:1624
isLoading undefined
```

The "orderStatus" in the HTML prints as `[object Object]` and isLoading returns as `true`.

Then when Option 2 is selected the following prints to the console and there is no change on the page:

```
Object { "InstrumentationResult :  ( RECEIVED = 9 , Topic = AILTN )  , TracingResponse : ( AsyncResults )": {…} }
BeaconLibrary.js:35:44
Proxy { <target>: {}, <handler>: {…} }
orderActivate.js:4:1873
{} orderActivate.js:4:1921
isLoading undefined orderActivate.js:4:1624
isLoading undefined
```

Its almost like the `"$orderId"` in the `getRecords` function never gets passed through.  However, this parameter is set no later than the `connectedCallback` as is shown in the console.

This is driving me mad, as it appears correct as far as I can tell.  The order record here definitely exists and is visible to the user.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**added from comments:**

In this [link](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetRecordStaticContact/wireGetRecordStaticContact.js), they did not actually miss ***fields***, its shorthand notation for Object initializer in [ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

So, both below options are valid:

```
var o = { 
  a: a,
  b: b,
  c: c
};
```

is same as below in ES2015

```
var o = {a, b, c};
```

---

1. You are missing ***fields*** attribute in **getRecord**
2. Wired service returns **data** and **error**, so you need to pass the ***data*** from **getRecord** to **getFieldValue**:

**getRecord:**

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$orderId', fields: ORDER_FIELDS })
wiredOrder;
```

**order status getter:**

```
get orderStatus() {
    if (this.wiredOrder.data) {
        let fieldVal = getFieldValue(this.wiredOrder.data, FIELD_ORDER_STATUS);
        console.log(fieldVal);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fieldVal));
        return fieldVal;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Hey @salesforce-sas, you're right!  Thank you so much!

I was following the code here and didn't notice that they missed that attribute: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetRecordStaticContact/wireGetRecordStaticContact.js

Comment: They didnt actually miss it, added in answer for clarification

Comment: Wow, thanks man for that!  I had no idea that existed.